# Return single row per year from a data table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to show only single row from each year based on the following data.

```
AlbumID     AlbumIcon                   Year
2       53575dd7-9e6a-4230-afe7-eb34a9952ef5.jpg    2010
6       41c6cefe-aa9a-40af-86bf-0e78784fc9be.jpg    2011
7       20472dc8-abff-4cb1-80a4-ec264a91025e.jpg    2011
9       a2185c73-debf-4058-afee-dc54caf674d2.jpg    2012
10      3e3de287-b966-40cc-8895-9c9e98f1b23d.jpg    2012
11      f0743e3e-26d8-44ea-97ad-a7bd33259550.JPG    2007
12      dafd1242-19d6-4f66-8b23-75143f107743.JPG    2012
13      d623e134-3d69-4b86-86fe-4c5a2ab89086.JPG    2012
14      9c6b981e-e696-4c85-be6d-3b04559a6cd4.JPG    2012
15      b6b867c0-5478-4503-940c-ce75e863bee8.JPG    2012
16      3cc0d762-f1e1-425a-8923-0e39b4ed0eca.jpg    2012
```

my Table structure is like this

```
Album_ID int
Album_Name varchar(100)
Album_Description varchar(500)
Album_Date Datetime
Album_Icon varchar(60)
```

I am using `SELECTAlbum_ID, Album_Name,Album_Icon, DATEPART(YYYY,Album_Date) AS Year FROM Album_Name` I am not sure how to modify the query to just get single row from each year and the latest year row would be great.

I want to achieve this without using CTE query

Group by with DISTINCT generates errors

```
SELECT Album_ID, Album_Name,Album_Icon, DISTINCT(DATEPART(YYYY,Album_Date)) AS Year FROM Album_Name  GROUP BY DATEPART(YYYY,Album_Date) , Album_ID, Album_Icon
```

Help in this regarding is appreciated.

Solution Based on Bagdan reply.

```
SELECT  *
FROM 
(
    SELECT  x.*,  
           --ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY x.[Album_Date] ORDER BY x.Album_ID DESC) AS RowNum
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY DATEPART(YYYY,x.[Album_Date]) ORDER BY x.Album_Date DESC) AS RowNum
    FROM    Album_Name x
) src
WHERE src.RowNum = 1
```

Comment: do u want min or max albumid to be returned for each year. Like for example, for 2011, should albumid be 6 or 7?

Comment: Do you want the latest row per year? The earliest? Highest ID?

Comment: Actually it should be based on Date rather than albumID as we can add 2003 album in 2013 and albumid is auto incremented.

Comment: Which of the rows you want e.g. 6 or 7 in 2011?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM 
(
    SELECT  x.Album_ID, x.Album_Name, ...,  
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY x.[Year] ORDER BY x.Album_ID DESC) AS RowNum
            -- or ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY x.[Year] ORDER BY x.Album_Date DESC) AS RowNum
    FROM    dbo.MyTable x
) src
WHERE src.RowNum = 1
```

**Edit #1:**

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE
(
    Album_ID int,
    Album_Name varchar(100),
    Album_Description varchar(500),
    Album_Date Datetime,
    [Year] smallint,
    Album_Icon varchar(60)
);

INSERT @MyTable (Album_ID, Album_Icon, [Year])
SELECT 2 , '53575dd7-9e6a-4230-afe7-eb34a9952ef5.jpg', 2010
UNION ALL SELECT  6 , '41c6cefe-aa9a-40af-86bf-0e78784fc9be.jpg', 2011
UNION ALL SELECT  7 , '20472dc8-abff-4cb1-80a4-ec264a91025e.jpg', 2011
UNION ALL SELECT  9 , 'a2185c73-debf-4058-afee-dc54caf674d2.jpg', 2012
UNION ALL SELECT  10, '3e3de287-b966-40cc-8895-9c9e98f1b23d.jpg', 2012
UNION ALL SELECT  11, 'f0743e3e-26d8-44ea-97ad-a7bd33259550.JPG', 2007
UNION ALL SELECT  12, 'dafd1242-19d6-4f66-8b23-75143f107743.JPG', 2012
UNION ALL SELECT  13, 'd623e134-3d69-4b86-86fe-4c5a2ab89086.JPG', 2012
UNION ALL SELECT  14, '9c6b981e-e696-4c85-be6d-3b04559a6cd4.JPG', 2012
UNION ALL SELECT  15, 'b6b867c0-5478-4503-940c-ce75e863bee8.JPG', 2012
UNION ALL SELECT  16, '3cc0d762-f1e1-425a-8923-0e39b4ed0eca.jpg', 2012;

SELECT  *
FROM 
(
    SELECT  x.Album_ID, x.Album_Name, Album_Icon, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY x.[Year] ORDER BY x.Album_ID DESC) AS RowNum
            -- or ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY x.[Year] ORDER BY x.Album_Date DESC) AS RowNum
    FROM    @MyTable x
) src
WHERE src.RowNum = 1
```

Comment: References: [ROW_NUMBER() function](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734(v=sql.90).aspx)

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker: See Edit #1

Comment: I made small change to your sql to make it work otherwise it was getting me all the rows. I will update my question with part of working query.. Thanks..

Comment: I address Datepart so get get distinct based on date part other wise i have distinct dates and it was returning all the rows...

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker: This query gives you one row per [Year] (" I am not sure how to modify the query to just get single row from each year"). If you want last album (last year - last album) then you coud remove `PARTITION BY`.

Comment: your solution is fine i just made small change `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY DATEPART(YYYY,x.[Album_Date]) ORDER BY x.Album_Date DESC) AS RowNum`

Answer (score 0):

As you are looking for one row for each year you can use max (or min) function to get one album ID per year as below  -

```
SELECT Album_ID, Album_Name, Album_Icon, DATEPART(YYYY, Album_Date) AS Year
  FROM Album_Name a1
 where album_ID = (select max(a2.album_Id)
                     from album_name a2
                    where a2.album_year = a1.album_year)
```

Comment: it is not possible ..  even in given rows in question, this query will return rows only where album_ID in 2,7,11,16 and this is what you required right?

Comment: May be i must have made some mistake... but i still need to sort it on date field not albumid ..